# Extending Active Directory functionality in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, active-directory

On a flat LAN with multiple Windows 7 clients and a single Active Directory (server 2008) machine, I have a requirement to ensure that given AD users can only log on for a specified number of minutes every day, at the limit of which they are forcibly logged out, and cannot log back in until the next day.

In the absence of the built in facility to do this, I had wondered whether a bespoke solution might be possible in .NET. Any pointers as to where to begin with this would be very much appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: You could try to extend AD with custom attributes, but AD isn't the tool to do run-time monitoring of users and their connections, really.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah agree with @marc_s, you could use existing properties like "lastlogontimestamp" to find out when last time username was used, but Service based approach is better, which will run on that box and check how long the user has been logged in and log him out.

Or you might be lucky with exploring Policies, where you might be able to specify maxUsage. I think in "Parental Control" policies somewhere you can set maximum time account can be used for given period. (i think I have seen it in Windows 7)

Comment: lastLogonTimestamp isn't a suitable facility for this. It's accurate to roughly +/- 10 days. You'd need to use last logon statistics which was added in Vista/2008. This blog is a good starter - http://jeftek.com/218/display-previous-logon-information-for-vista-users/.

Comment: Thank you both - I did indeed go the service route here, with much success :)